# How to fix Upload image using php and mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I tried replacing mysql to mysqli, but I encountered an error in this code, it worked on mysql before. What is wrong?

Php:

```
<?php include "../../../_includes/config.php"; ?>
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_FILES['userAvatar']['name'])){
  $uploadedFile = "";
  if(!empty($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"])){
    $filename = $_FILES['userAvatar']['name'];
    $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["userAvatar"]["name"]);
    $file_extension = end($temporary);
    if((($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions)){
      $sourcePath = $_FILES['userAvatar']['tmp_name'];
      $targetPath = "../../../uploads/image/".$filename;
      if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)){
        $uploadedFile = $filename;
      }
    }
  }
  $display_name = $_POST['display_name'];
  $biography = $_POST['biography'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tb_users SET userDisplayName = '$display_name', userBiography = '$biography', userAvatar = '$uploadedFile' WHERE userLogin = '".$_SESSION['is_logged_in']['userLogin']."'") or die(mysqli_error());
  if($sql){
    echo "ok";
  }else{
    echo "err";
  }
}else{
  echo "err";
}
?>
```

Result always "err".

Comment: There are two places where you printed `echo "err";`, can you change the message so that you can easily identify which block has error. Also print the update query then copy and directly execute in db to ensure there is no error is with your sql.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:-

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE tb_users SET userDisplayName = '$display_name', userBiography = '$biography', userAvatar = '$uploadedFile' WHERE userLogin = '".$_SESSION['is_logged_in']['userLogin']."'") or die(mysqli_error($connect));
```

// no need of this

```
if($sql){
    echo "ok";
}else{
    echo "err";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below

```
<?php

 $dbhost = 'localhost:3306';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = '';
   $dbname = 'your db';
   $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
   }
   echo 'Connected successfully<br>';


session_start();
if(!empty($_FILES['userAvatar']['name'])){
  $uploadedFile = "";
  if(!empty($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"])){
    $filename = $_FILES['userAvatar']['name'];
    $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["userAvatar"]["name"]);
    $file_extension = end($temporary);
    if((($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["userAvatar"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions)){
      $sourcePath = $_FILES['userAvatar']['tmp_name'];
      $targetPath = "../../../uploads/image/".$filename;
      if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)){
        $uploadedFile = $filename;
      }
    }
  }
  $display_name = $_POST['display_name'];
  $biography = $_POST['biography'];

   $sql ="UPDATE tb_users SET userDisplayName = '$display_name', userBiography = '$biography', userAvatar = '$uploadedFile' WHERE userLogin = '".$_SESSION['is_logged_in']['userLogin']."'";

   if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
      echo "Record updated successfully";
   } else {
      echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
   }
   mysqli_close($conn);

}else{
  //echo "err";
}
?>
```

Comment: my code its work now, its my fault, name of input file is avatar not userAvatar :(